# Give filler new waypoints?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Is there a way to give a filler a new waypoint without rebuilding it? And can is there a way i can use waypoints further away from the filler?

Comment: by waypoints do you mean the gridlines it generates when it's placed?

Comment: Yeah, i have to keep rebuilding the machine setup the program and put the materials in when i have to change/make new waypoints/gridlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the size *before* placing the filler using [Land marks](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Land_Mark)

- You must set up the land marks to be a square (so you need 3 at least, 4 if you want to change the height)
- place the first landmark and then give it a redstone single (lever or torch) to bring up the guide lines.
- place your other landmarks along the lines to however big you need (max is 64 blocks away from original landmark)
- right click the *original* landmark to complete the grid
- place the filler along the outside of that grid touching a line.

You cannot give a filler a new 'box' to work in

Comment: "You cannot give a filler a new 'box' to work in" That pretty much answered it thanks.